# Why is my Open Graph image not showing (but it takes up space) even though the URL debugger detects it?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I set up my `og:image` like this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/my-og-image.jpg" />
```

Its dimensions are `1200x630`, just like the Open Graph documentation recommends. However, when I preview it in [Facebook's URL Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/), it doesn't show the image. It takes up expected space, but it's just a white surface.

Comment: I'm not allowed to share the actual data because it's from a client site, I just wanted to share this answer. I will see how I can set up some example permanent-ish site to post it here, but this seems to be a generic issue (not specific to my setup).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you also need to specify the dimensions for the image to show:

```
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="630">
```

It's a good practice anyway, because now Facebook won't have to calculate it dynamically.